# Anylogic: adjust value of stock over time with a certain factor

Tags: anylogic

I am having some issues adding a factor to a stock over time.
This is my setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cikfe.jpg
My goal is for instance that in year 0 the 'Required Budget' is 20 million. (set Initial value = 20 million I guess, right?)
In year 1 this increases with 5%, for example, to 21 million.
The following year this increases again with 5%, to 22,05 million and so on.
I try to do this with a Required Budget Trend parameter of 1.05, but it does not seem to work.
It looks so simple but I can't seem to figure it out. Do I need to use a Stock variable for this or should I use something else?

Comment: Just a general comment: if your model doesn't need continuous-time changes in the values (e.g., you only care about per-year 'ticks' of the model), system dynamics is overkill and performance-intensive. Just use a variable or parameter which is multiplied by 1.05 every year (or other relevant time interval) via an event.

Answer (score 0):

required budget trend should be 0.05 and not 1.05, if you are multiplying required budget with required budget trend

(you want 5% increase, not 105% increase)

Then you have to be careful about your time units and be sure that your increase is by year and not by month ... depending on your time units

Also for a more exact answer, you should check the time step in your model properties in order to be sure that it is calculated correctly

Comment: Okay that is the first step! Because now, after 5 years, the final stock value of the Required Budget is around 26 million. Yes this is the amount that should be paid in year 5, however I want to have the accumulated amount. So 20 million in first year + 21 million in the second year (approximately 110 million in total as final). How can I achieve that?

Comment: I should mention that I did not apply a Trend formula with the Budget Trend Variable, because I am not sure how to apply it properly. So i just used to input value 0.05 in this case